# Laravel /Angularjs Modal Save / Delete code does nothing on submit

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm working on a laravel/angularjs app that uses a bootstrap modal to save/edit and delete records
I'm having a hard time understanding what i'm doing wrong, it does not save/edit the record and doesn't do anything when the submit button is clicked.

Below is my Modal code (I've shortened it), please tell me what you think is wrong?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@{{form_title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form name="AccountsForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="account_name"
                           class="col-sm-3 control-label">Account Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control "
                               id="account_name"
                               name="@{{account_name}}"
                               placeholder="Account Name"
                               value="account_name"
                               ng-model="account_name"
                               required="true">
                          <span class="help-inline"
                                ng-show="AccountsForm.account_name.$invalid && AccountsForm.account_name.$touched">Account number field is required
                          </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE**
Adding app.controller JS code for saving/editing

```
    //save new record / update existing record
    $scope.save = function(modalstate, id) {
    var url = API_URL + "accounts";

    //append account id to the URL if the form is in edit mode
    $scope.id = id;
    if (modalstate === 'edit'){
        url = "accounts/" + id;}
    $http({
        method: 'POST'
    }).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        location.reload();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code should look like this:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@{{form_title}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form name="AccountsForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="account_name"
                       class="col-sm-3 control-label">Account Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text"
                           class="form-control "
                           id="account_name"
                           name="account_name"
                           placeholder="Account Name"
                           value="@{{account_name}}"
                           ng-model="account.account_name"
                           required="true">
                      <span class="help-inline"
                            ng-show="AccountsForm.account_name.$invalid && AccountsForm.account_name.$touched">Account number field is required
                      </span>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

```
     //save new record / update existing record
    $scope.save = function(modalstate, id) {
    var url = API_URL + "accounts";

    //append account id to the URL if the form is in edit mode
    $scope.id = id;
    if (modalstate === 'edit'){
        url = "accounts/" + id;}
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $.param($scope.account),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
    }).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        location.reload();
    });
}
```